# Data structure for Objects

Tags: object, data-structures

Which data structures I should store the real life 'objects' in?
I am not looking for computer representation. I am looking for different data structures for different item in real life access/storage etc. Is there any  study on this?

Update:
Based upon comments, I should remove the 'data' from data structures and simply looking for structures to store various objects in based upon usability rules.

Comment: creating a class and identifying attribute and deciding appropriate type for those attribute.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think we could help more if you expanded the question and gave us examples of what you are trying to represent / store.

Comment: /agree. A data structure **is** a computer representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit too vague to answer well, but in general you can think about using existing "objects"/models/representations of the abstract things you want to model or manipulate.

If those don't exist then you build your own.

Answer (score 0):

Which data structure to use completely depends on the type of action you are going to perform on your data.

Some data structures are useful for random access(Arrays) while others are fast for insert delete operation( linked list )
Some store key value pair( HashMap or TreeMap)

Different operation varies arithmetically from each other in terms of time and space.So use the data structure that suit your requirements properly.